# Build and Link zlib fails because CMake renames files?

Tags: c++, cmake, zlib

I have the following project structure:

```
project/
├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ src/
├─ libraries/
│  ├─ directxtk/
│  │  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  ├─ zlib/
│  │  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
```

`project/CMakeLists.txt` is my main executable. I want to utilize zlib in it.

In this `CMakeLists.txt`, i have the following lines:

```
target_include_directories(Project PUBLIC ${EXTERNAL_HEADERS_DIR})
add_subdirectory("${LINK_LIBRARY_DIR}/zlib")
add_subdirectory("${LINK_LIBRARY_DIR}/directxtk")
target_link_libraries(Project LINK_PUBLIC zlib)
target_link_libraries(Project LINK_PUBLIC DirectXTK)
```

`EXTERNAL_HEADERS_DIR` and `LINK_LIBRARY_DIR` both point to `Project/Libraries`.

I include zlib the following way: `#include <zlib/zlib.h>`

When I try to build and run now, I receive the following **compile** error:

```
...\Project\Libraries\zlib/zlib.h(34): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zconf.h': No such file or directory
```

apparently, CMake seems to rename `zconf.h` to `zconf.h.included`!?
How can I properly build this whole thing?

Edit: I have copy&paste'd `zlib/CMakeLists.txt` from the public website of `zlib`

Comment: You forgot to specify which **source file** is compiled when the error is triggered. It seems this is NOT a zlib source file but a file of your Project. Because your Project executable uses headers from zlib, you need to add appropriate **include directories** to that target. "... apparently, CMake seems to rename zconf.h to zconf.h.included!" - If you mean [that messages](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L73) from CMake, then CMake clearly tells, that `zconf.h` is generated in the zlib build directory. You need to specify that directory as include one for your Project

Comment: @Tsyvarev Indeed, it's a source file I wrote that includes `zlib.h`.
Can you tell me what exactly I need to do? I have the following line in my `CMakeLists.txt`, too:
`target_include_directories(Project PUBLIC ${EXTERNAL_HEADERS_DIR})`
which points to `Project/Libraries` and my files include it via `#include <zlib/zlib.h>`, which means the include is actually correct, isn't it?

I have adjusted the question.

Comment: `Project/Libraries` refers to the **source** directory of zlib. Reference to its **build** directory could be constructed as `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Libraries/zlib`. Exactly that directory contains `zconf.h`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, sorry, how do I do that?

Comment: In the same way as you have already done in your code: `target_include_directories(Project PUBLIC ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Libraries/zlib)`.